# Is there any way to let it snow on my linux mint destkop?

Tags: x11, mate-desktop, compiz, wallpaper

I want snow fall on my desktop really badly.

Tried [Xsnow](http://dropmix.xs4all.nl/rick/Xsnow/) (with Mate/Marco, Mate/Compiz and KDE/Kwin) but doesn't work.
Snow plugin for Compiz doesn't work anymore either.
Snow feature of KDE was removed.

Is there any other way to get the snow?

Comment: http://oreaus.googlepages.com/snow.tar.  try grabbing a fresh copy, extract it into your compiz directory and `make` `make clean` `make install`

Comment: @h3rrmiller Where is my compiz directory? Tried ~/.compiz and ~/.compiz/plugins, it always says `No rule to make target ``build/snow.lo', needed by ``c-build-objs'.  Stop.`

Comment: you need to extract snow.tar into your ~/.compiz directory, then navigate to the snow directory and run the makes

Comment: @h3rrmiller Tried that already and make said "No rule to make...." (the message in my previours comment).

Comment: Depending on your location, you might be able to take it out of the house — during winter — and just wait for it to snow :)

Comment: I've found a website, where someone had the same error and  they said that snow plugin is not compatible with Compiz 0.9.x . Any other ways?

Comment: xsnow works fine for me with Gnome and Ubuntu 12.04 (sudo apt-get install xsnow). Not sure if you want snow badly enough to switch to Gnome :)

Comment: Only 16 hours left, and I likely don't have enough time to see what's going on with this, and I'm not the best person to do so either. I hope someone answers your question. I'd like to know too. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `xsnow` after having killed the *desktop* application that covers the root window. Run `xkill` and click on the desktop. That works at least in LXDE where `pcmanfm` usually handles the *desktop*, but should work in other environments as long as they don't require there being a desktop window in the background and don't restart it automatically when it dies.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mate restarts the desktop app. At leas I saw xsnow working for a second.

Comment: Same problem for me too while trying to run `xpenguins`. Mate restarts desktop as soon as I kill it. It turns out one has to use some simple window managers to use `xsnow`.

Answer (score 3):

I thought that a lua script (started by [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/)) would be a good tool for this job. There's loads of conky examples on the internet (e.g. [here](http://desktopspotting.com/26/best-conky-configs-for-linux-desktop/) and [here](http://maketecheasier.com/7-beautiful-conky-configurations-for-your-linux-desktop/2011/06/09)),  which could be used to make it snow on your desktop only when it's snowing outside, for example.

I saw [on a forum](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=883811) that some guy had posted some video tutorials on how to write a lua script for fireworks as well as snow, but unfortunately he's taken them down from YouTube...

There is however some leftover code that could be used as a template, but unfortunately doesn't work in isolation.

If I had the time and inclination to learn lua and fix this myself, here's what I'd do:

1. Install conky. Mint probably has it in its package manager.
2. Save [that snowfall fragment](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=883811&s=190280a1401ed49736117de4f0347369&p=19810028&viewfull=1#post19810028) somewhere (e.g. ~/.conky/lua/snowfall.lua)
3. Add the following lines to ~/.conkyrc

   `lua_load /path/to/home/.conky/lua/snowfall.lua

    lua_draw_hook_pre snowday`
4. Run `conky`. Look for errors, and debug / comment lines out / add functions where necessary...

This is the basics of the `snowday` function, as usable by `conky`. I'd love to see this work actually!
What's missing? The `timer` and `Vector` classes, at least..

```
function conky_snowday()
    timer.Stop("fuller")

    local emt2 = ParticleEmitter(Vector(0,0,400))
        timer.Create("fuller", 0.1, 0, function()
        for i=1, 1000 do
            local snowparty = emt2:Add("particle/snow",LocalPlayer():GetPos() + Vector(0,0,1000))
            snowparty:SetVelocity(Vector(math.random(-700,700),math.random(-700,700),math.random(-300,-100)))
            snowparty:SetDieTime(4)
            snowparty:SetStartAlpha(0)
            snowparty:SetEndAlpha(255)
            snowparty:SetStartSize(5)
            snowparty:SetEndSize(math.random(0,3))
            snowparty:SetColor(255,255,255)
            snowparty:SetRoll(math.random(0,360))
            end
        end)
    emt2:Finish()
end
```

Comment: The function was originally made for GarrysMod, right? I'm afraid the only class here that is not missing is math. Also, "particle/snow" is probably a Valve particle file, and most of particle parameters are set in there. It would be hard to port it eg. to cairo (which is used by conky configs to draw all the fancy things).

Comment: Yes, you're right... I spent quite a while trying to find those Vector and timer classes, but it seems they'd need to be downloaded through Valve. So, `particle/snow` is probably also locked up in there, and would no doubt be written for DirectX, so yes, would be hard to port to OpenGL :( So I later had a look through the NVidia SDK samples; there's a `smoke` example, but which uses CUDA. `xsnow` seems to be the only current option...

Answer (score 1):

For all your holiday decorations try this:

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/XDecorations?content=167575

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of xsnow, working on many desktops (including raspbian):
https://www.ratrabbit.nl/ratrabbit/content/xsnow/introduction

And it is also available on sourceforge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure whether it will work for `xsnow` but here's what I did to solve `xpenguins` issue.
1. Install `openbox` and `obconf`
2. Logout of current sesion and start an `openbox` session.
3. Right Click -> start terminal -> `xpenguins` (may be `xsnow` for you)
For detailed description check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429606/why-is-xpenguins-not-generating-any-penguins-on-my-desktop/429701#429701).