# Why is 'xpenguins' not generating any penguins on my desktop?

Tags: linux-mint, x11

I'm trying to run the `xpenguins` on my linux mint 18.1 Mate (After watching someone doing it on his desktop on a youtube tutorial video). But when I run it I get this output:

`Redrawing overwritten desktop icons`

Only command that works is `CTRL-C`.
So what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there any way to let it snow on my linux mint destkop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/is-there-any-way-to-let-it-snow-on-my-linux-mint-destkop)

Comment: Please give me suggestions to improve my question(why -1?).

Comment: I've tried all of them , none of them worked. Anyone has any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research on this topic , I found out present Desktop Environments are causing the problem(they draw Desktop over root-Desktop or something like that. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/is-there-any-way-to-let-it-snow-on-my-linux-mint-destkop) for more info).
So I searched more about this issue and found something on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xpenguins/+bug/1272374). Still can't solve my problem.
Finally found something useful on [linux mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=196977) and [lifewire blog](https://www.lifewire.com/install-openbox-using-ubuntu-4051832). So here's what I did to see those penguins walking(and merry making) on my desktop.
1. Install openbox using `sudo apt install openbox obconf`
2. Logout of your current session and start a openbox session.(in Linux Mint I can do that by `session -> openbox` and then loging in).
3. Right-click any where and start terminal. Type `xpenguins` (if not already installed do it by doing `sudo apt install xpenguins`) and those penguins will appear without any issue.
4. To kill those cute little penguins , hit `CTRL-C`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://sourceforge.net/projects/xpenguins/ for a new version.

xpenguins-3.0.0 runs fine on mint and other desktops.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, it required installing [xorg-dev](https://askubuntu.com/a/393141/638128), [xpm](https://xpack.github.io/xpm/install/), [libgtk-3-dev](https://askubuntu.com/a/779067/638128), and [upgrading GTK](https://askubuntu.com/a/955980/638128). After that, it worked!!

Comment: It looks like you are well equipped to try xsnow too! https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/

Answer (score 0):

Try using IceWM window manager. It worked for me

Comment: Any wm which doesn't distrub the root window will work ,I think.