# xsnow does not work in manjaro kde

Tags: kde, manjaro

i installed **xsnow** & **xpenguins** program but none of them work for me.
i find out they need **main root window** (or root x window) to work which is "**probably**" invisible in my OS or is not available.
how can i make them work fine in my Operation system (by recompiling them or any other thing)?
the output of "**uname -r**" is:

> 4.19.45-1-MANJARO

i hope asked my question in the right place otherwise please introduce a link to search for solution

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55725/117549

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of xsnow available, which works in most desktop environments.
This version is available in debian-testing and the latest version is on sourceforge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately i am on manjaro which is arch based and not debian based:(
I wish xsnow be available for manjaro one day.
I love it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the newest version of xsnow in a virtual machine with manjaro xfce 18.1.1-191015 :
from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsnow/files/ download xsnow-2.0.13.tar.gz , then:

tar xf xsnow-2.0.13.tar.gz
  cd xsnow-2.0.13
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install

If everything went ok, xsnow is now installed as /usr/local/games/xsnow . In Manjaro
this is not optimal, but you can easily correct this:

ln -sf /usr/local/games/xsnow /usr/local/bin/xsnow

With standard settings, xsnow runs very badly on my virtual machine, I had to start xsnow like:

xsnow -alpha 0 -exposures

Note that xsnow keeps it's configuration in ~/.xsnowrc , so the next invocation does not need the flags.

Note: in manjaro-kde (manjaro-kde-18.1.1-191015-linux53) xsnow runs with default settings in a virtual machine.

[image: xsnow running in manjaro]